# rsync filter does not work, all files excluded

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to sync files with pattern `*/ls` from folder /bin to folder test:

```
mkdir test
rsync -avv --exclude='*' --include=*/ls /bin/ test/
ls test
```

And from the output the include filter failed to work:

```
[sender] hiding file ls because of pattern *
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: The wildcard excludes everything, it is as simple as that. (And takes precedence over inclusion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclusion and inclusion filters are evaluated from left to right.  In your command line, this means that everything is excluded.  The inclusion filter is not having any effect, as the exclusion pattern has already matched every conceivable name.

Instead, to copy every file called `ls` from `/bin` or any of its sub-directories, use

```bsh
rsync -av -m --include='*/' --include='ls' --exclude='*' /bin/ test/
```

Put the inclusion patterns first and exclude everything not explicitly included last.  You will need to match `*/` with an inclusion pattern as you may want to descend into subdirectories (at least in the general case).  I've also added `-m`, which avoids creating directories on the destination if there are no files in them.

If you don't need recursion and want `/bin/ls` copied with `rsync`, then use

```bsh
rsync -av /bin/ls test/
```

The slash at the end of the destination pathname in the two commands shown here is unnecessary but will force the command to fail if `test` is not a directory.  It acts as an assertion, in a way.